# circle window extruding doesnt work

Tags: modeling

I do this round window according the tutorial, but in his case everything is working and in my case while extruding the circle mesh nothing happens, it only moves

[image: tutorial circle extrusion]

1st picture is tutorial,2nd is mine

[image: mine]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't pay attention to switching to *Vertices* selection mode, I had *Faces* mode active, and that is why it didn't work

Comment: Glad you figured it out! You should mark your answer as accepted (the checkmark) if it works for you.